# Sum list of NumPy arrays without summing coordinates if the list is size 1

Tags: python, numpy, sum

If I have a list of numpy arrays and want to add them coordinate-wise: `np.sum()` does the job.

```
sum([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([6, 5, 4])])
>>> array([7, 7, 7])
```

But if my list happens to contain only one array, a new (and unwanted) thing happens:

```
sum([np.array([1, 2, 3])])
>>> 6
```

So how do I get the behaviour to be **consistent over all list sizes**? i.e. I want a function `f()` such that:

```
f([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([6, 5, 4])])
>>> array([7, 7, 7])
f([np.array([1, 2, 3])])
>>> array([1, 2, 3])
```

I am excluding `if len(lst) > 1:` type solutions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you have lists of arrays in the first place? Are the nested arrays the same size?

Comment: The `python` `sum` just does `array1 + array2 + ...`; it iterates on the first level of iteration, whether a list or an array.  `np.sum` applied to the same first turns it into a array, and uses the array sum method.  `np.array(alist).sum(...)`.  The numpy sum takes an `axis` parameter.  But either way you have to pay attention to the nesting or dimensions.

Comment: Are you sure that the two `sum`s you're using are the same? I can't reproduce your results: with `np.sum`, I get a single number as an answer in both cases (which is what I expect), and with Python's built-in `sum` I get an array in both cases (which is also what I expect).

Comment: I think @yatu raises a good point. Things aren't entirely clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy arrays can be sumed over arbitrary dimension. You'll need to transform this into a single array first:

`np.array([...]).sum(axis=0)`

As it was hinted in the comment, handling it as a numpy array from the start makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think so this one like..We can do so because logic is in the middle, so we can make the program work by changing the location.

IIUC, Use numpy.sum with axis=0:

np.sum([np.array([1, 2, 3])], axis=0)
Output:

array([1, 2, 3])
and

np.sum([np.array([3, 1, 2]), np.array([6, 5, 4])], axis=0)
Output:

array([7, 7, 7])

Comment: _We can do so because logic is in the middle_ Middle of what, and what does the middle have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the degree of nesting:

A list of 2 arrays:

```
In [93]: sum([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([6, 5, 4])])                                       
Out[93]: array([7, 7, 7])
```

A list of 1 array:

```
In [94]: sum([np.array([1, 2, 3])])                                                            
Out[94]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

One array, not a list

```
In [95]: sum(np.array([1, 2, 3]))                                                              
Out[95]: 6
```

A list of numbers:

```
In [96]: sum([1, 2, 3])                                                                        
Out[96]: 6
```

`sum` iterates on the argument, whether a list or an array. [93] works because arrays implement their own summation method.  It does not work on a list of lists.

Making sure the contents are a 2d array, generalizes these cases:

```
In [102]: sum(np.atleast_2d([[1, 2, 3], [6, 5, 4]]))                                           
Out[102]: array([7, 7, 7])
In [103]: sum(np.atleast_2d([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([6, 5, 4])]))                       
Out[103]: array([7, 7, 7])
In [104]: sum(np.atleast_2d([np.array([1, 2, 3])]))                                            
Out[104]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [105]: sum(np.atleast_2d(np.array([1, 2, 3])))                                              
Out[105]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [106]: sum(np.atleast_2d([1, 2, 3]))                                                        
Out[106]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

Or use the numpy sum with axis 0:

```
In [108]: np.atleast_2d([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([6, 5, 4])]).sum(axis=0)                
Out[108]: array([7, 7, 7])
In [109]: np.atleast_2d(np.array([6, 5, 4])).sum(axis=0)                                       
Out[109]: array([6, 5, 4])
```